# Difference between 8k block on 32bit VS 4k block on 64bit file system

Tags: operating-system, filesystems

Is there any difference between 8k block on 32bit file system vs 4k block on 64bit file system?

If there is, how big would the difference in the largest file size be? Would I calculate it the same way I would calculate 8k on 32bit and just change 4bytes on 32bit to 8bytes on 64bit?

Ex. 8k bytes w/ 32bit disk addresses
So 8192/4bytes = 2048*8KB = 16MB of file data (singly indirect)
and 2048*2048*8k = 32GB of file data (doubly indirect)

Ex. 4k bytes w/ 64bit disk addresses
4096/8 = 512*4k = 2MB of data (singly indirect)
and 512*512*4k = 10GB of file data (doubly indirect)

So if the example is true, there would be a big difference between the two (specially in triply indirect, which gives the max file size)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have real-world filesystems in mind, you can check the [maximum
file size on Wikipedia](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Blocks).
In particular, if it's ext4, the block size vs. number of bits
[doesn't change the max size of an individual file.](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Blocks)

If you're talking about a theoretical system, your calculations are
fine.  Do keep in mind that inode-based filesystems typically
have direct blocks as well, ext4 defines 12 of them.  So add 48k to
your 4k-block example, 96k to the 8k-block one.  And don't forget to add the triply-indirect blocks!